# AngularJS 1.3.11 - routeProvider is not loading the html partial

Tags: angularjs

Having some issues with routeProvider, I've been following the tutorial on the AngularJS page and for some reason it's not loading the html partial.

I don't have any errors showing in Chrome console debug.

I've tried moving the html file into the same folder as the .js files just to check if it's a directory issue and no change as nothing loads.

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
...
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
...
<div ng-view></div>
```

controllers.js

```
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', []);

artistControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http',    function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
    $scope.artistOrder = 'name';
});
}]);

artistControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
$http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
});
}]);
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'artistControllers']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/list', {
    templateURL: 'partials/list.html',
    controller: 'ListController'
}).
when('/details/:itemId', {
    templateURL: 'partials/details.html',
    controller: 'DetailsController'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
});
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `templateURL:` to `templateUrl:`.